# The method '+' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null' Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Why I keep getting this error message although I added the null checking?

```
 if (params.page != null) {
      ++params.page;
  }
```

**Error**

```
The method '+' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!')
```

Comment: `params.page = params.page! + 1;` do it like that

Answer (score 0):

You're probably trying to promote a field that is not private. As per Dart 3.2, type promotion for fields only works when the field is private.

See: [Only private fields can be promoted](https://dart.dev/tools/non-promotion-reasons#private)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
if (params.page != null) {
    params.page++;
}
```

Comment: This won't work either.  It has nothing to do with pre-increment vs. post-increment.

Comment: Yes you are right I am just guessing it is it possible for you to share the params object and demo values of it ? 
So I can test it out

Comment: or a reproducible error code

Comment: It's quite trivial to reproduce.   [Non-`final`, non-private fields simply cannot be type-promoted](https://dart.dev/tools/non-promotion-reasons).  Additionally, [increment/decrement operators cannot be used on nullable types](https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1113).

Answer (score -1):

## Here is an example of how you can use the null check operator to

avoid this error:

```
if (params.page != null) {

  params.page++;

}
```

If you want to use the null check operator, you can modify the code

as follows:

```
params.page?.let { params.page++ }
```

This will ensure that the method ‘+’ is only invoked if the

receiver is not null. I hope this helps!

Comment: This won't actually work.  https://github.com/dart-lang/language/issues/1113